# Resource search does not exist - LinkedIn API

Tags: linkedin-api

I have some issue with linkedin api. The search endpoint (to search posts by keyword) is not accessible to me. I got permissions for Marketing Developer Platform. My permission scope is:

r_1st_connections_size,r_ads,r_ads_reporting,r_basicprofile,r_organization_admin,r_organization_social,rw_ads,rw_organization_admin,w_member_social,w_organization_social

I assumed search endpoint would be included into this scope. Do I miss anything?

I am trying to use search api in the following way: https://api.linkedin.com/v2/search?q=LinkedIn API&type=post and using my access token. But I get error:

```
{
   "serviceErrorCode": 0,
   "message": "Resource search does not exist",
   "status": 404
}
```

Comment: Have you reviewed the API documentation? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/

Comment: Thanks for reply! Looks like search is deprecated and now is replaced with companySearch https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/company-search?context=linkedin%2Fcompliance%2Fcontext&view=li-lms-unversioned&preserve-view=true&tabs=http#search-for-companies
However, I cant find which product/scopes I require to use it

Comment: Most likely the 'r_compliance' permission is what's needed.

Comment: Based on documentation, nothing from what I see is related to search posts by keywords. It is either finding organization/company information (companySearch) or find info on specific posts given post urn (socialActions). Is there any product/api that I can use to search posts by any keyword?